# Bash == operator in [[ ]] is too smart!

Tags: linux, bash

Case in point. I want to know if some set of files have as a first line '------'.

So,

```
for file in *.txt
do
    if [[ `head -1 "$file"` == "------" ]]
    then
        echo "$file starts with dashes"
    fi
done
```

Thing is, head returns the content with a newline, but "------" does not have a newline.

Why does it work?

Comment: @Vinko , I just did a man head but I did not find a mention of the use of newline while displaying the content

Comment: It shows the first N *lines* of a file and lines are defined by newlines, so it shows the complete line, with its newline included

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The backticks strip the trailing newline. For example:

```
foo=`echo bar`
echo "<$foo>"
```

prints

```
<bar>
```

even though that first echo printed out "bar" followed by a newline.

Comment: Relevant BASH Manual quote: 
"Bash performs the expansion by executing command and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command, with any trailing newlines deleted."

Answer (score 0):

Bash performs word splitting on the result of command substitution i.e. `head -1 "$file"`

Word splitting will remove newlines among other things.